# Angular ui-router and module conflict

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have different modules. If a user try to view a profile page, he gets redirected to the index page to login. `app.profile.routes` has an `Auth` functionality to do that, but it also applies to `app.index.routes`, why? Is it something to do with `$rootscope` or is my module dependency setup is wrong?

For instance, if I try to view a url that's defined in app.index.routes, I am asked to log in.

`app.feed.routes` is the route file of `app.feed` and `app.index.routes` is the route file of `app.index`.

I have a main index.html (ng-app="app" is defined there) and I merge every .js file into one file called index.js

```
router.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
});
```

Here's my main app.js.

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngMaterial',
  'ngMessages',
  'hm.readmore',
  'ng-fx',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.router',
  'app.feed',
  'app.profile',
  'app.index'
]);

angular.module('app.feed', ['app.feed.routes']);

angular.module('app.feed.routes', []);

angular.module('app.profile', ['app.profile.routes']);

angular.module('app.profile.routes', []);

angular.module('app.index', ['app.index.routes']);

angular.module('app.index.routes', []);
```

profile-routes.js

```
angular.module('app.profile.routes')
 .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth',
  function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
      var val2 = function() {
        return Auth.isLoggedIn().then(function(rt) {
          if (rt.data.length) {
            console.log("text " + rt.data.length);
          }
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log("please sign in");
          var shouldLogin = toState.data !== undefined && toState.data.requireLogin;
          console.log(shouldLogin);
          $state.go('login');
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      };
      val2();
    });
  }
])
```